# onkeyup event in Safari on IOS7 from a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: safari, bluetooth, ios7, keyup, onkeyup

I have the following setup:

- Bluetooth scanner
- iPad
- Webpage with a textfield for scan input

Usage:

- User focus textfield and scan barcode with bluetooth scanner
- Scanner adds ENTER (13) at the end of the scan

Problem:

On Safari in IOS7 there seems to be a change on how keyboard events are handled on bluetooth devices.
The code ...

```
window.onkeyup = function (e) {
    console.log(e.KeyboardEvent)
}
```

... should return information about the key pressed. Instead i get ...

```
keyCode: 0
keyIdentifier: "Unidentified"
```

... no matter which key I press.

Same result booth form bluetooth scanner and bluetooth keyboard.

Thanks / E

Comment: if anyone stumbles upon this: still having this issue 4 years later https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924702/ipad-bluetooth-keyboard-returns-keycode-of-0-for-any-key-with-onkeyup

Answer (score 3):

Seems that "onkeypress" works as expected though.

Since this was a problem a bumbed in to in a Sencha Touch project and Sencha Touch doesn't have a keypress event on textfields I'm posting the code that solved my problem.

```
{
    xtype:'searchfield',
    name:'search',
    placeHolder:'search',
    listeners: {
        painted: {
            fn: function () {
                var me = this;
                me.element.dom.onkeypress = function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        me.fireEvent('searchkeypress', me, e);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem @EmilPennlov. I was able to solve this by using a $watch on the input field. Worked like a charm.