# JS keydown keyup keypress event doesn't work on IOS8 when using third party IME

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios8, mobile-safari

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
  alert(event.which);
}
```

On IOS 7, this works when using system default IME, but doesn't work when using third party IME. It seems the third party IME doesn't send keydown/keyup/keypress event.

Any workaround to monitor an Enter key pressed?

P.S. This issue is similar to [iOS 8 3rd party keyboards don't register javascript/jQuery keyup, keypress, keydown etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080368/ios-8-3rd-party-keyboards-dont-register-javascript-jquery-keyup-keypress-keyd?rq=1), but any workaround to monitor 'Enter' key pressed event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985117/onkeyup-event-in-safari-on-ios7-from-a-bluetooth-keyboard This seems to be similar to your problem. Perhaps you may try to use the .onkeypress event instead.

Comment: this is different, the key press event is not triggered when using third party IME in IOS, but it works fine with system default IME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out a workaround

```
  $("#textarea").on('input propertychange paste',function(e){
    var input = e.currentTarget.value;
    if(input[input.lenght -1] == '\n') {
      //do something
    }
  })
```

1. Use textarea replace input
2. Add 'input propertychange paste' listener on textarea
3. check if Enter is the last character of the textarea value