# iPad Bluetooth keyboard returns keycode of 0 for any key with onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, bluetooth

Some clients have been reporting issues when using their iPad Bluetooth keyboards for entering text into one of our internal sites. Mainly pressing enter on a certain input would work fine when using desktop or the iPad on screen keyboard, but not when using a Bluetooth keyboard connected to the iPad.

Upon investigation it appears that any input to an `onKeyUp` returns 0 as the keycode when connected to a Bluetooth keyboard on the iPad. The demo works fine, however when using the onscreen keyboard it doesn't work because of the keycode returning 0. [I created this jsFiddle to demonstrate.](https://jsfiddle.net/f07dbxj9/) It was tested on both Chrome and Safari for iPad with the same results of working fine with `onKeyPress` but returning only 0 with `onKeyUp`.

```js
$('#inputKeyUp').keyup(function (event){
 $("#outputKeyUp").text("Key Up Key: " + event.which);
});

$('#inputKeyPress').keypress(function (event){
 $("#outputKeyPress").text("Key Press Key: " + event.which);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputKeyUp">keyup</textarea>
<div id="outputKeyUp">Key Up Key:</div>
<b/>
<textarea id="inputKeyPress">keypress</textarea>
<div id="outputKeyPress">Key Press Key:</div>
```

EDIT: just reported the bug to Apple. We will see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Just tried it myself, same issue (iOS 9). Looks like this has been an isue for a while: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985117/onkeyup-event-in-safari-on-ios7-from-a-bluetooth-keyboard. It might be a bug in Safari. Does the same thing happen on a different browser?

Comment: @Sidney yes, I tested it in Chrome as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Testing study

I did some testing on this just now and discovered that on the `keyUp` event when using a Bluetooth keyboard on iOS Safari, the only keys that give any sort of proper feedback in terms of the properties `e.key`, `e.charCode`, `e.keyCode` and `e.which` are the following keys:

- Escape
- Up arrow
- Left arrow
- Right arrow
- Down arrow

All other keys return the following:

```
{
    key: "Dead",
    charCode: 0,
    keyCode: 0,
    which: 0
}
```

These special keys (escape and arrow keys) only return a different value on the `e.key` property according to the syntax `UIKeyInput{PascalCasedKeyName}`:

- `UIKeyInputEscape`
- `UIKeyInputUpArrow`
- `UIKeyInputLeftArrow`
- `UIKeyInputRightArrow`
- `UIKeyInputDownArrow`

### Summary

On iOS, the only keys you can identify on the `keyUp` event, based on my quick study, are `Escape` and the four `Arrow keys`, by matching their name on the `e.key` property. These values also appear on the `keyDown` event.

If you still need to wait until the `keyUp` event fires for your applications, and you need to match keys other than these special ones, the only solution I can come up with is to use a `keyDown` event for capturing the key, but then listen for the `keyUp` event *inside* that `keyDown` event like so:

```
el.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.which === 13) // Enter key, or which ever key code you'd like
        el.addEventListener("keyup", function keyUp(e) {
            el.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false) // Memory clean-up

            // Your code here
        }, false)
}, false)
```

### Furthermore

After a quick search for "UIKeyInput" I discovered that `UIKeyInput` is "a set of methods a subclass of UIResponder uses to implement simple text entry". ([Apple's Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput)) This would explain the special syntax of these key names.

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround for the enter key in the keyup event.

```
if (event.type === 'keyup') {
    //this is to handle the enter button on an ipad bluetooth keyboard
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.which = event.keyCode = 13;
    }
}
```